# Moving tuple of cells using VBA script

Tags: vba

I have a bit strange situation in Excel. It looks like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A        2       2
A        2       3
A        2       4
B        2       3
```

What I want to do is to have a VBA script which will make something like this. The "A" or index from Column 1 is the one that should match.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3      Col4   Col5   Col6      Col7    Col8    Col9
A        2       2         A      2       3        A        2       4


B        2       3
```

I tried moving around VBA but with no results. I can't wrap my head around creating a tuple with those cells (there is like 50 000 rows). I want this to work on every row and in the end produce such effect as presented.

Comment: What code did you try? How is it failing? We can help you fix it, but asking us to solve your problem from scratch for you is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Visual Basic for Applications and I'm stuck with creating variable that holds all three values from columns (in this example something like this - A, 2, 2). I know it's tuple but I have no idea how to create it so it would cover all rows in the excel document, one by one. 

If I'll know how to declare such variable I think I will be able to create loop which will help me to find repeating item1 from each of the tuple.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using, as Mathieu suggests.

Comment: As @MathieuGuindon said, please provide the relevant code

Comment: Hi, sorry for such late response, I was sick. 

Well, I know how it may sound but setting columns as variable was something I wished to start with but frankly it stopped me right at the beginning (I just started using VBA, and I had no experience in VB at all, so I'm learning on the fly). So I can't provide a code, just an idea what I'm trying to achieve. But I think igorsp7 has covered my vague question. I'll improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tuples in VBA, but there are class modules, i.e. classes that can be used instead. For example, you can add a class module `MyTuple` with 3 public fields:

```
Option Explicit

Public Col1 As Variant
Public Col2 As Variant
Public Col3 As Variant
```

Then you can instantiate your variable and use it like this:

```
Dim t As MyTuple
Set t = New MyTuple
t.Col1 = "..."
t.Col2 = "..."
t.Col3 = "..."
```